# Woocommerce emails from gmail not being sent

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

Not sure if this is wordpress or woocommerce-specific but I've run into an issue where emails aren't being sent out if the FROM email is my personal gmail.

- When the FROM header is set to info@mydomain.com, I receive emails immediately
- When the FROM header is set to mygmail@gmail.com, I don't get any emails.
- When the FROM header is set to info@blahblahblah.com, I receive emails immediately

According to WP Mail Logger, emails were sent out with no errors in all instances. It's funny that the third email actually gets sent out, given that I have no control over [blahblahblah.co although it does seem to be registered](https://www.whois.com/whois/blahblah.com)

Is this a gmail security thing? I do find it kind of suspicious that I'm able to enter completely random emails and claim to send emails from them, but how would I debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Most recieving mail systems will reject an email with a 'from' of someone@otherdomain.com when the email is sent from the mydomain.com system. This is to prevent mail relaying, a form of spam.

You need to make sure that your 'from' email address matches your domain. The actual email address (like someone@mydomain.com for mydomain.com) doesn't need to exist, but the mydomain.com in the email must match the mydomain.com domain name of the sending mail server.

You can always set the 'reply-to' of an email as someone@gmail.comm, and that mail will be delivered through yourdomain.com mail server. That allows someone to reply to your gmail account.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's generally my understanding of what mail servers would do with mismatched domains, so it was interesting to see that emails sent from info@blahblahblah.com actually went through.

Maybe gmail is just selective about what's considered mismatched domains.